# how does tomcat like web container handle struts 2 variables?

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

i am a newbie . i have a question regarding struts 2 framework and tomcat . i know that each request has it own thread , but my question is are the global variables defined in struts action shared amongst requests. 
  for ex: if i have a global variable named say 
          int pageNo; and i am using in say method called paginationAll() 
can i use the same variable (pageNo) for another method called say paginatonMaterialAll() in the same action or does each thread has its own set of variables even though globally defined?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what are those "global variables" defined in you action. Java does not have "global variables" (you mean static fields or what?)

Answer (score 1):

In **Struts 1** it wasn't advisable to have globally scoped variables/fields in your action classes - they were shared between all requests.

However, in **Struts 2** I believe this has changed - Actions are now constructed for each request.

See:

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/comparing-struts-1-and-2.html

> Struts 2 Action objects are instantiated for each request, so
>   there are no thread-safety issues. (In
>   practice, servlet containers generate
>   many throw-away objects per request,
>   and one more object does not impose a
>   performance penalty or impact garbage
>   collection.)

Answer (score 1):

Global shared variables don't sound thread safe to me.  I'd rethink that design.

Answer (score 0):

YOur question is not very clear, but it this helps: in Struts2 a new instance of the Action object is created for each request.